# Stream microphone audio over rtsp

Tags: audio-streaming, rtsp, microphone

Need to create an rtsp server in C# which streams the audio from my microphone.Is it possible to do that? I have fetched the data from microphone and is available as bytes.

Comment: What platform are you on? I'd start by Googling `<name of your platform> create rtsp audio server`

Comment: i need it using C#

Comment: So Google it. If there's a way, there's guaranteed to be lots of good results.